# Libreoffice macro has infinite loop

Tags: macros, libreoffice

Can someone point out what's wrong with this macro please? I'm trying to search for paragraphs with the token "vv", then change their paragraph style to "_Verse". This macro works if I place a breakpoint in it and go manually one paragraph at a time. But when left on its own it maxes out the CPU core and I have to force LO down.

The problem seems to be that the line
`Loop While oEnum.hasMoreElements()` does not pick up on having reached the end of the file.

Thank you.

```vb
sub findvv

rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object

oEnum = ThisComponent.Text.createEnumeration()
rem
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
rem 

dim args1(21) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

    args1(0).Name = "SearchItem.StyleFamily"
    args1(0).Value = 2
    args1(1).Name = "SearchItem.CellType"
    args1(1).Value = 0
    args1(2).Name = "SearchItem.RowDirection"
    args1(2).Value = true
    args1(3).Name = "SearchItem.AllTables"
    args1(3).Value = false
    args1(4).Name = "SearchItem.SearchFiltered"
    args1(4).Value = false
    args1(5).Name = "SearchItem.Backward"
    args1(5).Value = false
    args1(6).Name = "SearchItem.Pattern"
    args1(6).Value = false
    args1(7).Name = "SearchItem.Content"
    args1(7).Value = false
    args1(8).Name = "SearchItem.AsianOptions"
    args1(8).Value = false
    args1(9).Name = "SearchItem.AlgorithmType"
    args1(9).Value = 1
    args1(10).Name = "SearchItem.SearchFlags"
    args1(10).Value = 65536
    args1(11).Name = "SearchItem.SearchString"
    args1(11).Value = "^vv"
    args1(12).Name = "SearchItem.ReplaceString"
    args1(12).Value = ""
    args1(13).Name = "SearchItem.Locale"
    args1(13).Value = 255
    args1(14).Name = "SearchItem.ChangedChars"
    args1(14).Value = 2
    args1(15).Name = "SearchItem.DeletedChars"
    args1(15).Value = 2
    args1(16).Name = "SearchItem.InsertedChars"
    args1(16).Value = 2
    args1(17).Name = "SearchItem.TransliterateFlags"
    args1(17).Value = 1073743104
    args1(18).Name = "SearchItem.Command"
    args1(18).Value = 0
    args1(19).Name = "SearchItem.SearchFormatted"
    args1(19).Value = false
    args1(20).Name = "SearchItem.AlgorithmType2"
    args1(20).Value = 2
    args1(21).Name = "Quiet"
    args1(21).Value = true

Do
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExecuteSearch", "", 0, args1())

    applyverse

Loop While  oEnum.hasMoreElements()

end sub

sub applyverse

dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "Template"
    args1(0).Value = "_Verse"
    args1(1).Name = "Family"
    args1(1).Value = 2

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:StyleApply", "", 0, args1())

end sub
```

Comment: Your loop will always run at least once? If `oEnum.hasMoreElements()` is false already at the first repeat, what happens then? *Besides that, when you wish to have people peek at your code, please make SOME effort to format it as is tradition; e.g. indent the portions that are inside subs, loops and other conditionals at least two columns.*

Comment: @Hannu - Yes, with a break point, the macro will successfully find one paragraph and change its style. I'll see if I can reformat, sorry.

Comment: Looking a lot better ;-)  *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It seems to me that* you are unnecessarily mixing two methods in one code. To solve the described problem, one of them is sufficient.
If you have all the paragraphs of text obtained via `.Text.createEnumeration()`, then simply get the next paragraph using `oEnum.nextElement()`, read its text value using `.getString()` and check the left two characters to match the **vv** pattern

```
Sub setVvAsVerseEnum
Dim oText As Variant
Dim oEnum As Variant
Dim oPara As Variant
Dim sString As String
    oText = ThisComponent.getText()
    oEnum = oText.createEnumeration()
    While oEnum.hasMoreElements()  
        oPara = oEnum.nextElement()
        sString = oPara.getString()
        If Left(sString,2) = "vv" Then oPara.ParaStyleName = "_Verse"
    Wend  
End Sub
```

If you want to use the built-in regular expression search, then create a search descriptor, indicate in it the search pattern and the need to search using regular expressions. Using one command `.FindAll()`, find all paragraphs corresponding to the template and assign the desired paragraph style to each of them

```
Sub setVvAsVerseByFindAll
Dim oSearchDescriptor As Variant
Dim oFound As Variant
Dim oPara As Variant
    oSearchDescriptor = ThisComponent.createSearchDescriptor()
    oSearchDescriptor.setSearchString("^vv.*$")
    oSearchDescriptor.SearchRegularExpression = True
    oFound = ThisComponent.FindAll(oSearchDescriptor)
    For Each oPara In oFound
        oPara.ParaStyleName = "_Verse"
    Next oPara
End Sub
```

Both codes do the same job, and both codes are a little shorter than what the macro recorder generated for you *(and I think it's a little easier to read, doesn't it?)*

Comment: Wow, thanks. Amazing. I need to study these, they are a study in efficiency. Thanks again. Marked Solved.